# Setting visibility of select tag based on selection in prior select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I want to have my States select dropdown only be visible after a country has been chosen in a prior dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" autofocus>
    <br />
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
    <br />
    <select name="country" onchange="showStates()" id="country">
        <option>Select A Country</option>
        <option id="US" value="US">USA</option>
        <option id="AUS" value="AUS">Australia</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name="State" style="display:none;" id="us-states">
        <option>Select A State</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name="State" style="display:none;" id="aus-states">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select A State</option>
        <option value="TAS">Tasmania</option>
        <option value="QLD">Queensland</option>
        <option value="VIC">Victoria</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <br />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Here is the showStates() function:

```
function showStates() {
    var selected = $('#country :selected').text();

    if (selected == "US") {
        document.getElementByID('us-states').style.display = "block;"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementByID('us-states').style.display = "none;";
    }

    if(selected == "AUS") {
        document.getElementByID('aus-states').style.display = "block;"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementByID('aus-states').style.display = "none;";}
    }
}
```

I'm finding that the program initially hides the select boxes, but doesn't redraw them when a new option is selected in the country tag.

Comment: replace `document.getElementByID`     by `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using jQuery you can do away with the inline function call. Just add a change handler, and use the value of `#country` to determine which element to show:

```
$('#country').on('change', function() {

   var country = this.value.toLowerCase();

   $('select[name="State"]').hide() 
                            .filter('#' + country + '-states') 
                            .show();
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46ZvA/7/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, on my local machine it doesn't appear to run correctly. I've verified that jQuery is running, however the javascript simply just doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: @user2234378 Make sure the above is wrapped within `$(document).ready(function() { // code above goes here });` - this ensures that the dom is ready before trying to manipulate its properties

Comment: +1 for using properties to dynamically select elements, rather than hard-code checks. This allows for easier future changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way using jQuery:

```
$('#country').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();

    if(selected === "US") {
       $('#us-states').show(); 
    }
    else {
       $('#us-states').hide(); 
    }

    if(selected === "AUS") {
        $('#aus-states').show(); 
    } 
    else {
        $('#aus-states').hide(); 
    }
});
}
```

[**Fiddle Example HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mnLhh/)

**OR:**

```
$('#country').on('change',function()
{
var selected = $(this).val();

showStates(selected);

});
```

**ShowStates Function:**

```
function  ShowStates(value)
{
    if(value === "US") {
$('#us-states').show(); 
}
else {
$('#us-states').hide(); 
}
if(value === "AUS") {
$('#aus-states').show(); 
} 
else {
$('#aus-states').hide(); 
}
}
```

[**Fiddle With Existing Function Reuse**](http://jsfiddle.net/mnLhh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
function showStates(id)
{
$("#"+id).css("display", "block");
}

$("#country").on("change", function(){
    showStates('us-states');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lukx8/